# STM32L152RE Schematic Verfication & Feedback

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, schematics, arm

I am making a custom PCB for an academic project. I will be grateful if somebody can verify the schematic I created for STM32L152RE and if I have made any mistakes. I will be using SWD to flash code to the STM32. The selected boot option is System Memory.

[image: Updated STM32L152RE Schematic based on feedback]

Comment: Your question is too generic on the one hand because it leaves open what mistakes you might anticipate, on the other hand it is very specific to this particular MCU. So it's difficult to answer and brings little benefit to the community. Maybe you can try to formulate it more specific to expected problems?

Answer (score 1):

Why BOOT0 is set to boot from system memory? It means the bootloader, doing so does not allow you to boot your uploaded application. Set BOOT0 to low.

Comment: I would be doing a lot of debugging and flashing. So it does make sense to boot from the main flash memory. The AN3216 shows BOOT0 = 0 and BOOT1 = x. Does it mean I set BOOT0 to low and leave the BOOT1 pin unconnected (floating)?

Comment: When BOOT0 = 0, BOOT1 = X means it does not matter and can be ignored. I'd sill prefer perhaps pulling it low. But I would pull BOOT1 low, because if you ever want to user the internal bootloader to load firmware via UART without JTAG, then temporary jumper or button to set BOOT0 = 1 is handy.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things.
First off I would add a reset switch, it comes in handy.

Second, if you'll actually be using any of your analog(ADC/DAC/COMP), then I would go with a second regulator for VDDA and not just a ferrite bead.  I would also add a 1uF cap to VDDA.  Make sure you've got a storage cap where your power enters the board, 4.7uF to 10uF should work.

Last, you do know that the L1XX's are old and slow chips?  The L0 and L4/L4+ will have more flash/ram, lower power and better peripherals than any of the L1XX's.  And if you don't require low power, go with a F0/F3/F4.

Comment: I would most probably not be using ADC, DAC or the Comparators. I chose STM32L152RE because it has two I2S interfaces and it is low power. Also, I chose this MCU because of its availability in India. 

Thanks for the recommendation for the 4.7uF storage capacitor and the reset switch.

Comment: For light usage then, keep the bead and go ahead and add the 1uF also.   The analog will still be quite useful for in the ballpark if not better.

Answer (score 1):

To add to what the previous answers have said. For the BOOT0/1 pins, it is usually handy to have them tied to a DIP switch or at least a push button to switch between GND and VCC. Especially since this seems to be a prototype for a project, it's better to have the ability to change boot states and not need to than the alternative.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on the boot states, please? AN3216 does talk about boot states but it is a little confusing. I would need the MCU to be reprogrammed through SWD. So would BOOT0=0 and BOOT1=x work as recommended in AN3215. Does x here mean floating? Do I need to remove the associated lines for BOOT1?

Comment: Ok, from AN3216, with BOOT0 pulled low(BOOT1 is don't care), you'll boot into flash.  With BOOT1 low and BOOT0 high you'll be in boot loader mode.  With both high you'll boot from internal SRAM(Never seen this one used).  You said your using SWD, so just pull BOOT0 low through a resistor and forget about it.  The only time you need jumpers is if your using a boot loader.